# Implementing photo slides from ios library like photo app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Does anyone know how to implement a photo slider action sheet in xcode like the photos app? Iv been searching around and couldn't find anything that worked this is ios8 and xcode6 please reference the screen shot below from the photos app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sideways scrolling mechanism for swiping through photos in the photo picker is a UIScrollview.

What you will want to do is create a UIScrollview within your View, then populate it with the items you wish to scroll through. The way to ensure that it is horizontally scrolled in the Scrollview is to set the width parameter to the width of the total count of items in the Scrollview.

For example, if you create a scrollview with 10 images, you will want to set the scrollview's width property in ViewDidLoad of the main View to (image.width*10).

The most basic way to do this would be:

1. Set up View, add a Scrollview
2. In Viewcontroller, create property and assign Viewcontroller as UIScrollview delegate
3. Instantiate the scrollview in ViewDidLoad
4. Set width of the Scrollview manually (width of each image * number of images). You may want to add some padding using the built in content inset methods so they aren't directly bordering eachother.
5. Use the scrollview.addSubView(images) method for all images to be added